# PyInstaller exe file | How to update

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I've made a script for tkinter test and made exe for the same but project is only in initial stage so do I need to uninstall that exe and if yes how to do so or do I just need to create another exe and that will overwrite existing exe.

Comment: Essentially, I think the installer you used will give the app an ID and as long as you keep the ID same, I think it will update each time you open the installer, assuming you used an installer in the first place.

Comment: Thanks I tried and executable was made without any issues